# Finding eigenvalue and eigenfunction of the boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

How to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this boundary value problem?
$$
y'' + \lambda y = 0 \\
y'(0)=0, y(\pi/2)=0
$$
I want to find only positive eigenvalues. I proceed like this:
$$
y=C_1 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x) + C_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)\\
y(\pi/2)=0 \Rightarrow C_2=0\\
\therefore y=C_1 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda }x \\
y'=-C_1 \sqrt{\lambda } \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x) \\
y'(0)=0 \Rightarrow -C_1 \sqrt{\lambda } \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)
$$
So, $C_1=0$ or $\lambda=0$. In these cases, we only get trivial solution.

So, does any value of $ \lambda $ is eigenvalue? Or have I made errors?

Comment: How do you get $C_2 =  0$?

Comment: @John  $C_2sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\frac{\pi}{2})=0$  but sine function is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity $\lambda\mapsto\lambda^2$, then we have 
$$
y'' + \lambda^2y = 0
$$
which is the differential equation for SHO. Thus, $y(x) = A\cos(\lambda x) + B\sin(\lambda x)$. The first BC we should use is $y'(0) = 0$.
\begin{alignat}{2}
y'(0) &= B\lambda &&{}=0\\
B &= 0\\
y(x) &= A\cos(\lambda x)\\
y(\pi/2) &= \cos(\lambda\pi/2) &&{}=0
\end{alignat}
Cosine is zero when the argument is $n\pi/2$ where $n$ is an odd integer. Therefore, $\lambda = 2n-1$. Your eigenfunction is then
$$
y_n(x) = A_n\cos[(2n-1)x]
$$

Comment: $\cos(\lambda\pi/2)=0$ if $\lambda=1,3,5,7,9,\cdots$.

Comment: @T.A.E. good catch.